# Automatically number a word in description if used at least twice

Tags: numbering, description

I defined an environment with `description` which automatically numbers the bold words if they appear twice or more often in an `\item[]`.

So far it works fine, but I cannot add a `1` to the first word, if the word appears more often in a "incorrect" order (see ME).

Here is my as-minimal-as-possible example and what I have done so far (needs two runs):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{
adieresis={ä}, germandbls={ß},
}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%%%
\makeatletter

\newcounter{dcounter}
\newcounter{ecounter}

  \def\Tipps@item[#1]{\g@addto@macro{\ListeII}{[#1]}%
  \if@noparitem
    \@donoparitem
  \else
    \if@inlabel
      \indent \par
    \fi
    \ifhmode
      \unskip\unskip \par
    \fi
    \if@newlist
      \if@nobreak
        \@nbitem
      \else
        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
        \addvspace\@topsep
        \addvspace{-\parskip}%
      \fi
    \else
      \addpenalty\@itempenalty
      \addvspace\itemsep
    \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
  \fi
  \everypar{%
    \@minipagefalse
    \global\@newlistfalse
    \if@inlabel
      \global\@inlabelfalse
      {\setbox\z@\lastbox
       \ifvoid\z@
         \kern-\itemindent
       \fi}%
      \box\@labels
      \penalty\z@
    \fi
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty \@M
    \else
      \clubpenalty \@clubpenalty
      \everypar{}%
    \fi}%
  \if@noitemarg
    \@noitemargfalse
    \if@nmbrlist
      \refstepcounter\@listctr
    \fi
  \fi
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#1%
    % Is #1 on the list?
\IfSubStr{\Liste}{#1}{%
    % If it is
\def\inhalt{#1}%
% How often is #1 in \ListeII
\StrCount{\ListeII}{[#1]}[\Number]%
% If \Number is 1 do nothing, else print \Number
\ifnum\Number=1\relax\else~\Number%
  % If Number is 2 make a label
  \ifnum\Number=2 \label{\thedcounter\theecounter}\fi%
\fi%
}{%
% If not: Add to list
\g@addto@macro{\Liste}{ #1 }%
\stepcounter{dcounter}%
% is label r@\thedcounter\theecounter defined or not?
\@ifundefined{r@\thedcounter\theecounter}{}{~1}%
}%
:}}%
  \global\setbox\@labels\hbox{%
    \unhbox\@labels
    \hskip \itemindent
    \hskip -\labelwidth
    \hskip -\labelsep
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
      \box\@tempboxa
    \else
      \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}%
    \fi
    \hskip \labelsep}%
  \ignorespaces}

\def\Tippsitem{% 
  \@inmatherr\Tippsitem 
  \@ifnextchar [\Tipps@item{\@noitemargtrue \Tipps@item[\@itemlabel]}} 

% - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

\newenvironment{Hinweis}{\def\Liste{}\def\ListeII{}% make lists empty
\setcounter{dcounter}{1}% setcounter back to one
\stepcounter{ecounter}%
\let\item\Tippsitem% 
\begin{description}} 
{\end{description}} 

\makeatother
%%%%%

\begin{document}

% In "correct" order -> works fine :)
\begin{Hinweis}
\item[Fuß] In "correct" order -> works fine :)
\item[Fuß] For the problem look at the next list
\item[Fuß]correct
\item[was]correct
\item[Ärger]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Hmmm\dots]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\end{Hinweis}



And here is the problem:
 % In "incorrect" order -> doesn't work fine :(
\begin{Hinweis}
\item[Fuß] Here should be a \textbf{1}
\item[Ärger] No 1
\item[Fuß] correct
\item[Fuß] correct
\item[Hmmm\dots] correct
\item[Würfel] Should be a \textbf{1}
\item[was] No \textbf{1}
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\end{Hinweis}

\end{document}
```

As you can see  the numeration of the second list is wrong.

You can find my first try [here (second post)](http://www.golatex.de/nummerierung-bei-eigener-umgebung-t10671.html), but I do not like the solution because it did not allow me to use `\dots` and I had to build a macro to be able to use `ß`, etc... and so I made a new one (this one).

I hope someone has an idea how to solve this numeration problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Sorry, is an old habit ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way with `environ`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{environ}

%%%%
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{Hinweis}{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{%
    \def\hinw@list{}
    \let\item\hinw@tempitem
    \BODY\expandafter}%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\hinw@list\expandafter{\hinw@list}
  \def\do##1{\@namedef{hinw@\detokenize{##1}}{0}}\hinw@list
  \let\latex@item\item
  \let\item\hinw@item
  \begin{description}\BODY\end{description}}
\def\hinw@add#1{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\hinw@list\expandafter{\hinw@list\do{#1}}}
\def\hinw@tempitem[#1]{%
  \@ifundefined{hinw@\detokenize{#1}}
    {\@namedef{hinw@\detokenize{#1}}{}}{\hinw@add{#1}}%
}
\def\hinw@item[#1]{%
  \@ifundefined{hinw@\detokenize{#1}}
    {\latex@item[#1]}
    {\@nameedef{hinw@\detokenize{#1}}{\number\numexpr\@nameuse{hinw@\detokenize{#1}}+1\relax}%
     \latex@item[#1 \@nameuse{hinw@\detokenize{#1}}]}}
\providecommand\@nameedef[1]{\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

%%%%%

\begin{document}

% In "correct" order -> works fine :)
\begin{Hinweis}
\item[Fuß] In "correct" order -> works fine :)
\item[Fuß] For the problem look at the next list
\item[Fuß]correct
\item[was]correct
\item[Ärger]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Hmmm\dots]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\end{Hinweis}



And here is the problem:
 % In "incorrect" order -> doesn't work fine :(
\begin{Hinweis}
\item[Fuß] Here should be a \textbf{1}
\item[Ärger] No 1
\item[Fuß] correct
\item[Fuß] correct
\item[Hmmm\dots] correct
\item[Würfel] Should be a \textbf{1}
\item[was] No \textbf{1}
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\item[Würfel]correct
\end{Hinweis}

\end{document}
```

The entire environment is first typeset in a temporary box where the various item names are examined and, if one of them appears at least twice, it's stored in a list; after that the list is used to define suitable commands that expand to the number. Using `\detokenize` should make this independent of the document encoding. Here I used UTF-8, but it works also with Latin-1 (tested).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I added the `:` myself. PS: It also works on Applemac.

Comment: @Epllus Sorry for the colon. It's really better if you switch to UTF-8 for your documents.

Comment: @egerg Don´t worry about the colon. Hmm... I often heard that utf8 is better, but I never had disadvantages with applemac.  I hope switching the encording via `% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` is alright.